# When coding with Datomic - why does println and pprint treat temporary ids differently?

Tags: clojure, pretty-print, datomic

In Datomic, I can get a temporary ID like following:

```
(ns demo
  (:require 
    [datomic.api :as d]
    [clojure.pprint :refer :all])))

(d/tempid :db.part/db)
```

Now when you output this using `println` you get something similar to:

```
(println (d/tempid :db.part/db))
;#db/id[:db.part/user -1000003]
```

Now I understand this is a temporary id.

However when I do the same thing with pretty-print - I get something different:

```
(pprint (d/tempid :db.part/db))
;{:part :db.part/user, :idx -1000002}
```

Why is this different? Is there something fundamental about temporary IDs I'm missing?

**Assumptions:**

- Here are my dependencies in Leiningen:

  `:dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.6.0"]
                  [com.datomic/datomic-free "0.9.5130"]]`

My question is: **When coding with Datomic - why does `println` and `pprint` treat temporary ids differently?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like `d/tempid` returns either a record or an object with a custom `toString` method. While `println` prints records with their name, `pprint` prints them as plain maps. Try this on the REPL:

```clj
user=> (defrecord MyRecord [a])
user.MyRecord
user=> (def m (My. 1))
#'user/m
user=> (println m)
#user.My{:a 1}
nil
user=> (clojure.pprint/pprint m)
{:a 1}
nil
```

`#user.My{:a 1}` doesn't look exactly like `#db/id[:db.part/user -1000003]` but you can see the difference between using `pprint` and `println` for things like records or other objects.

Edit: `(type (d/tempid :db.part/user))` returns `datomic.db.DbId` which is a custom type.